# ZoomUS - Android Crash - ZoomSDK

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, zoomus

Use https://github.com/mokriya-org/react-native-zoom-us-bridge

On Android, when I click join, the app closes, leaving only a "Meeting in progress" notification and not allowing access.

**Permisions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />

buildscript {
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
}
```

include ':app',':mobilertc', ':commonlib'

React Native version:
Yarn Android
React Native 0.6.3

Steps To Reproduce
Yarn Android
Join Meeting

Comment: Hi @JadrDev, welcome to StackOverFlow. Can you give more details about your situation: related pieces of code and the error you get during the crash.

Comment: Hello Olga, the code that I use the code that I share above. https://github.com/mokriya-org/react-native-zoom-us-bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been to add the line to the build.gradle in the path Android / App / build.grandle

implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'